# Kafka max.request.size vs. buffer.memory vs. send.buffer.bytes

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm trying to configure my Kafka producer, and going over the documentation I'm trying to understand the best correlation between the different values.

From what I understand, these values must obliged to the following rule:
max.request.size >= buffer.memory >= send.buffer.bytes. setting values outside of these rules won't make sense. am I correct? what's the best guideline rule to set these values (assuming max.request.size = X)?

Also, assuming ack=1, does the max.in.flight.requests.per.connection has any meaning?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

These three are not related to each other. In fact, default values for them are:

> max.request.size: 1048576
>
> buffer.memory: 33554432
>
> send.buffer.bytes: 131072

So "max.request.size >= buffer.memory >= send.buffer.bytes" does not hold, since they concern different things.

As for max.in.flight.requests.per.connection, it controls whether the producer should honor the sending order for messages, which is also no related with acks.

Comment: I'm missing something:
If the producer waits for ack after each message, how can we lose order? (I don't send another message before acking the first)
As for the sizing issues, I understand why the send.buffer is smaller, but why would I hold a larger buffer than the request size? further more, isn't the max.request.size and batch.size redundant? (Why would I hold a larger batch size if I can't send it in one request? and why configure a large request if the batch.size is smaller which means the request will be sent by batch.size anyway??)

Comment: If two batches are sent to the same partition, and the first fails due to some reason and is retries(assume you enable retrying) but the second succeeds, then messages in the first batch may arrive later where out-of-order occurs.

Comment: Producer employs a buffer into which messages are accumulated. Later a separate IO thread will take messages from the buffer and wrap them into a PRODUCE request, so you definitely wants this buffer to be reasonably large. In doing so can the IO thread always have something to do instead of waiting.

Comment: As for your last concern, a PRODUCE request contains multiple batches. Tuning these two parameters could help improve throughput.